# Async methods causing 404 errors in app start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using `async` methods in my global.asax file, and am experiencing a problem.

Even though the `async` methods are working as they should, when I fire them in `Application_Start()` I get 404 errors when my app starts, until it's done, when it shouldn't complete until it's done.

Here's the code in my global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected async void Application_Start()
    {
        var Init = new Init();
        await Init.LoadAsync();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking since `Application_Start()` had to be made `async` to allow an `await` command, the `Application_Start()` function itself is not being awaited when the app starts.  Therefore, it's necessary to find out either how to `await` the `Application_Start()` function or another way to fire the method without having to make `Application_Start()` an `async` method (The latter would be preferred).

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET does not seem to allow aysnc for Application_Start. However, you can use async for BeginRequest by using `HttpApplication.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(BeginEventHandler, EndEventHandler)`. Have a flag to indicate whether your Init.LoadAsync has been called so that you will only trigger the initialization on the very first request.

Then set up Application Initialization Module to create that first request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpApplication_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: They allow it alright, just can't override it's caller maybe.  I was actually able to remove `async` and `await` and even though I get a warning, it still runs.

Comment: The problem with not awaiting the LoadAsync is that request can come in while your LoadAsync is still running, thus that request might run into uninitialized states. I have to verify if Application Initialization Module does block real requests before it completes though

Comment: I don't see how it is a problem for concurrent requests--My understanding is when you don't `await` it runs in sync

Comment: Well I was wrong, I'm getting errors now on uninitialized objects.